# What's special about localhost for browsers?

Tags: browser, localhost

As far as I know, browsers treat localhost and other domains differently. Like, not everything works on localhost. Do you know what specifically is different? What does "localhost" means in this context? Anything that resolves to `127.0.0.0/8`? What about port/scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [following article](https://web.dev/when-to-use-local-https/) the special things about `localhost` are:

- Although it's HTTP, it's generally treated as HTTPS.
- You can't set a cookie on localhost that is `Secure`, or `SameSite:none`, or has the `__Host` prefix.
- You can't reproduce mixed-content issues.
- Browsers don't (Not all browsers) rely on DNS resolvers for localhost and subdomains.

And "localhost" in this context means `localhost` and subdomains, with or without a custom port.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, browsers treat localhost and other domains differently. Like, not everything works on localhost.

Quite the opposite. `http://localhost` is considered a *secure origin* by many browsers, so you can do development with many features that would normally be disabled without HTTPS.

See [When is a context considered secure?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts#when_is_a_context_considered_secure):

> A context is considered secure when it meets certain minimum standards
> of authentication and confidentiality defined in the Secure Contexts
> specification. A particular document is considered to be in a secure
> context when it is the active document of a top-level browsing context
> (basically, a containing window or tab) that is a secure context.
>
> For example, even for a document delivered over TLS within an
>
> , its context is not considered secure if it has an ancestor
> that was not also delivered over TLS.
>
> However, it’s important to note that if a non-secure context causes a
> new window to be created (with or without specifying noopener), then
> the fact that the opener was insecure has no effect on whether the new
> window is considered secure. That’s because the determination of
> whether or not a particular document is in a secure context is based
> only on considering it within the top-level browsing context with
> which it is associated — and not whether a non-secure context happened
> to be used to create it.
>
> Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs,
> http://localhost and  http://*.localhost URLs (e.g.
> http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered
> to have been delivered securely.
>
> Note: Firefox 84 and later support http://localhost and
> http://*.localhost URLs as trustworthy origins (earlier versions did
> not, because localhost was not guaranteed to map to a local/loopback
> address).
>
> Resources that are not local, to be considered secure, must meet the
> following criteria:
>
> - must be served over https:// or wss:// URLs
> - the security properties of the network channel used to deliver the resource must not be considered deprecated